# Paging in Extjs with WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, extjs

I have got a problem with put grid's paging params in my URI (WCF service).

Here my 'store' code for my grid:

```
Ext.define('KP.store.Listls', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'KP.model.Listls',

    autoLoad: true,

    pageSize: 50,
    autoLoad: { start: 0, limit: 50 },


    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',           
        startParam: undefined,
        api: {

        read: '/adres/listls?page=' + 1  + '&size=' + 20            
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',           
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }     
    }

});
```

And here my code of interface service:

```
 [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        //UriTemplate = "/list",
        UriTemplate = "listls?page={page}&size={size}",                
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
    )]
    List<Person> GetLs(string page, string size);
```

The problem is in this code string:

```
read: '/adres/listls?page=' + ???  + '&size=' + 20
```

What param I will to use for understanding page number?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy, but it's doable. You would need to implement two things:

1. Change your ExtJs reader use `$skip` as your `startParam` and `$take` as your `limitParam`. And you don't need to implement any special logic to parse this on the WCF end. It already understands `$skip` and `$take`.
2. Change WCF side to send total number of records somehow. Because by default when pagination is used total number of records sent inside JSON object would be -1.